# Can't see time at the top of my app because the top bar is dark

Tags: ios, react-native

So this is a pretty dumb question. But the color scheme of the app includes a lot of black, including the top bar, this hides the black characters of the time. Is there any way to get the time to show up white instead of black specifically for this app? Or should I just change the color scheme.

Comment: Do you use `StatusBar` component?

Answer (score 1):

This should make it white

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

Comment: OK thanks! I wish I could give you a publicly recorded upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Project target and change the property like:

[image]

**Changing Status Bar Style to Light Content will change it for your full app.**

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!