# Status Color won't change

Tags: ios

I'm trying to change my the color of the status bar on my application.
As default, the color right now is white (I never set it up) and my color of the background is also white, so I can't really see the status bar.
I tried changing it in my ViewController by adding this property:

```
private var style: UIStatusBarStyle = .default
```

this is my preferredStatusBarStyle:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return self.style
}
```

and on viewDidAppear I tried this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    style = .default
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

This is an answer I saw here on Stackoverflow, but it just won't work for me.
I tried changing the navigationBar barStyle also, also didn't work.

I'm using a TabBarController embedded in NavigationController, tried to change both navBarColor / preferredStatusBarStyle, also didn't work.

Info.plist Picture:
[image]

Comment: Is this solving your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394686/2781088

Comment: @MohitKumar Thanks, I already tried changing the options there, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your info.plist

Comment: @MohitKumar I added the relevant section of the info.plist.

Comment: Please check the answer below, if this solves your issue. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```swift
    private(set) var isDark: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return isDark ? .darkContent : .lightContent
        } else {
            return isDark ? .default : .lightContent
        }
    }

    final func changeStatusBarStyle(isDark: Bool) {
        self.isDark = isDark
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = isDark ? .default : .black
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the status bar remains white. I tried to look again if I changed it somewhere, but nothing, I never set it up at all.

Comment: Maybe your view controller is contained in another controller that is overriding your preference. I’ve subclassed UINavigationController specifically to deal with the status bar color and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Set your status bar color here:

[image]

Step 2: Add this entry to .plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Now your status bar color will not be viewController based and whatever color you will set in Step 1, will reflect in the full app.

Please let me know if this solves your issue.